# Filtering by day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a column that needs to be filtered by day of the week. The format of the column is:

```
(00/00/yyyy) (06/09/2017)
```

Now I have to filter every Tuesday of the week.

I need a syntax which can show only data for Tuesday. I do not have a day of the week column which isdate column has `(00/00/0000)`. I am using Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: what format is 00/00/yyyy?

Comment: What version and type of SQL?

Comment: I quick way would be to `INNER JOIN` to a Calendar Table by the date and with the day of week. Calendar Tables are something that should be in every database. They are immensely useful.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `Oracle`  or `SQL Server`) that you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

In `SQL Server` you can use `DATENAME()` function :

```
. . . 
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATE) = 'Thursday';
```

This assumes `DATE` has resonable format else you would need to adjust the date format using `cast/convert` function.

Comment: Is DATENAME() a RBAR operation? That might heavily impact a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I am soundly of the opinion that a Calendar Table / Date Dimension should be created for every database. It is exceptionally useful precisely for situation like this. And it can scale very well.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63c32/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
/* My test table for dates. */
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int identity, myDate date) ;

INSERT INTO t1 ( myDate )
VALUES 
    ('2018-01-01')
  , ('2018-01-02')
  , ('2018-01-03')
  , ('2018-01-04')
  , ('2018-01-05')
  , ('2018-01-06')
  , ('2018-01-07')
  , ('2018-01-08')
  , ('2018-01-09')
  , ('2018-01-10')
;

SET DATEFIRST 7;  /* Make sure Sunday is the first day of the week. */

/* My calendar table / date dimension. */
CREATE TABLE cal
(
  [date]       DATE PRIMARY KEY, 
  /* Add whatever parts you need easy access to. */
  [day]        AS DATEPART(DAY,      [date]),
  [month]      AS DATEPART(MONTH,    [date]),
  [year]       AS DATEPART(YEAR,     [date]),
  [DayOfWeek]  AS DATEPART(WEEKDAY,  [date])
)
;

INSERT INTO cal ([date])
VALUES 
    ('2018-01-01')
  , ('2018-01-02')
  , ('2018-01-03')
  , ('2018-01-04')
  , ('2018-01-05')
  , ('2018-01-06')
  , ('2018-01-07')
  , ('2018-01-08')
  , ('2018-01-09')
  , ('2018-01-10')
;
```

**Now it's just a simple query.**:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM t1
INNER JOIN cal ON t1.myDate = cal.[date]
  AND cal.[DayofWeek] = 3  /* Tuesday */
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63c32/1/0)**:

```
| id |     myDate |
|----|------------|
|  2 | 2018-01-02 |
|  9 | 2018-01-09 |
```

I've always found Aaron Bertrand's example of creating a Calendar Table to be an excellent resource: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Oracle setup is a little bit different. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea3612d5e4e97fe0aef7194f5c5fffb3 Also note that `ALTER SESSION SET nls_territory = 'AMERICA' ;` is used to make sure that the day of the week gets the number we need. You will have to adjust this for the Locality of your data. I also had to change some of the column names since I used some "special" words, like `[date]`.